# Reactjs Hooks Array with Objects is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a array that I am adding objects too however when I attempt to add a additonal object to the array so that I have [{object1}, {object2}] it gives me a error saying that the Array is not iterable. Here is my const and then the code I'm using to add the new data to the Array.

```
const [allPlans, setAllPlans] = useState([]);


setAllPlans(prevPlans => [...prevPlans, {price: 'price_1553OzIDkO5GB1Bj2W46fkAHc', quantity: 1}])
```

But I get that error and I've tried a lot of different methods but not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Each object contains a price and a quiantity.I've used this method before to add to an array but it was just a array of strings but it worked. Yet this does not. Thank you!

Update: Earlier in the code I do update the array before it gets to this point doing this. Could this be creating the issue? It's because I allow the user to adjust the quantity after the initial data is inserted.

```
setAllPlans(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        "quantity": userAmount
    }));
```

Comment: `setAllPlans(prevPlans => { console.log(prevPlans) })` <- it is array?

Comment: That returns 

{price: 'price_1M4UpFIRkO5W1JjEWkWQBZqE', quantity: 2}
price
: 
"price_1M4UpFIRkO5W1JjEWkWQBZqE"
quantity
: 
2
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Which is the value of the first object in the array.

Comment: Maybe can you put your full code into a codeSandbox or something? The code in the question doesn't seem to be wrong.

Comment: You have an array changing to an object somewhere. Perhaps you are changing the state somewhere else.

Comment: I made a update to the post and added in the code that I'm changing it prior to this point.

Comment: Yes. You put an object in the state, not an array. To avoid such errors, use TypeScript or JSDoc

Comment: what should I be doing when I modfiy the quantity on the previous entry then?

Comment: Do you have some data about where is the index of this entry in the array which you want to modify?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by removing the code where I had updated the value previously and changed the code to this line:

```
setAllPlans(allPlans => [[{...allPlans}], [{price: 'price_1553OzIDkO5GB1Bj2W46fkAHc', quantity: 1}]])
```

This worked!